# Using the filter function in Python

Tags: python, csv, filter

I am trying to use Python's built-in filter function in order to extract data from certain columns in a CSV. Is this a good use of the filter function? Would I have to define the data in these columns first, or would Python somehow already know which columns contain what data?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input data and the requested output data?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Maybe show an example? It's not clear to me...

Comment: Sure thing. Let's say my CSV has columns 1,2, and 3. I want to ignore all the data in column 2, and extract only what's in columns 1 and 3. Can this be achieved using the filter function?

Comment: That's not much of an explanation, but I guess it's something to go on...

Comment: You should read CSV files with the stdlib's csv module, as in "number5"'s answer bellow. The `filter` built in is better left for other uses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` function is intended to select from a list (or in general, any iterable) those elements which satisfy a certain condition. It's not really intended for index-based selection. So although you *could* use it to pick out specified columns of a CSV file, I wouldn't recommend it. Instead you should probably use something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    for record in csv.reader(f):
        do_something_with(record[0], record[2])
```

Depending on what exactly you are doing with the records, it may be better to create an iterator over the columns of interest:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    the_iterator = ((record[0], record[2]) for record in csv.reader(f))
    # do something with the iterator
```

or, if you need non-sequential processing, perhaps a list:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    the_list = [(record[0], record[2]) for record in csv.reader(f)]
    # do something with the list
```

I'm not sure what you mean by defining the data in the columns. The data are defined by the CSV file.

---

By comparison, here's a case in which you would want to use `filter`: suppose your CSV file contains numeric data, and you need to build a list of the records in which the numbers are in strictly increasing order within the row. You could write a function to determine whether a list of numbers is in strictly increasing order:

```
def strictly_increasing(fields):
    return all(int(i) < int(j) for i,j in pairwise(fields))
```

(see the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) for a definition of `pairwise`). Then you can use this as the condition in `filter`:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    the_list = filter(strictly_increasing, csv.reader(f))
    # do something with the list
```

Of course, the same thing could, and usually would, be implemented as a list comprehension:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    the_list = [record for record in csv.reader(f) if strictly_increasing(record)]
    # do something with the list
```

so there's little reason to use `filter` in practice.

Answer (score 7):

Since python boasted "batteries included", for most the everyday situations, someone might already provided a solution.
CSV is one of them, there is [built-in csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Also [tablib](http://readthedocs.org/docs/tablib/en/latest) is a very good 3rd-party module especially you're dealing with non-ascii data.

For the behaviour you described in the comment, this will do:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   for row in reader:
      row.pop(1)
      print ", ".join(row)
```